# Enthought Traits Equivalent of dataclasses.dataclass frozen=True?

Tags: immutability, traits, enthought

How can I make Enthought HasTraits class instances immutable post initialization - something equivalent to @dataclasses.dataclass (frozen=True) ?
Thanks,
/jim
Python 3.9.4
Traits 6.2

Comment: are you still looking for an answer?

Comment: I stopped using Traits, because of a few issues I could not resolve (this one included) so now an answer would be more of a curiosity.